How to get notification updates from Microsoft about all Azure services?
We required the notifications for all the services that we have consuming for example we require Alerts for retiring or Upgrades/Patches etc...
Basically all the updates.
Note: I found this URL: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/
But I don't see the proper information for the above URL.
I did lot of research and I don't find any proper information.

To receive notifications about Azure services, Microsoft provides several resources. You can subscribe to Azure Health Service Issues through Azure Monitor to receive notifications about service interruptions and planned outages. Additionally, you can use Azure Service Health to receive notifications about ongoing service issues, planned maintenance, and health advisories.


You can also subscribe to Azure Updates through the RSS feed to receive information about software updates, termination of support for older preview OS versions, and similar information.

To subscribe to Azure Update through the RSS feed:

Go to the  Azure Updates  website.
In the  Search all updates  box, enter  the service for which you want updates for example Azure Sphere.
Right-click the  RSS feed  button and select  Copy link.
Use the copied URL in any RSS reader to subscribe to the RSS feed.



Ensure you have the rss feed reader extension enabled on your browser for the above process to work.

References:

Quickstart: Subscribe to Azure Sphere notifications
Stay current with Azure
Stay informed about Azure security issues
Get automated service notifications through APIs
Azure Cognitive Services support and help options

